# How can I trim white-space and replace trimmed space with a semicolon?

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a project where there are hundreds of eCommerce product features separated by white-space. The number of spaces differs from row to row. I need to reformat all these cells with multiple features with a semicolon.

**Example**

> Flat                                    Belt tabs for use with 4237, 4247                                Not made with natural rubber latex

**Desired Output**

> Flat;Belt tabs for use with 4237, 4247;Not made with natural rubber latex

[image]

Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome. Please share a test sheet bearing dummy data as well as expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the limited info on your question, most likely the formula you need is:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K9,"\s{2,}",";"))
```

The regular expression `\s{2,}` will pick any stings with 2 or more white spaces which will be then replaced by `;`.
The above formula will produce a single column where each cell will hold the results
(eg. `Flat;Belt tabs for use with 4237, 4247;Not made with natural rubber latex`)

If you on the other hand wish your results to be separated to more columns you can add the `SPLIT` function:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(K4:K9,"\s{2,}",";"),";",0,1))
```

Functions used:

- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: I apologize for the limited information. The solution you provided was exactly what I needed. I very much appreciate you taking the time to supply an answer!

Comment: Glad my solution worked out for you. _"...limited information"_. Please keep in mind that **a sample sheet always helps**.